# Cardinality of Set of Matrix satisfying some conditions.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Let S be a set of all $3*3$ matrices with integers entries such that $A*A'$$=$$I$.
Find $|S|$.
$ |  |$ means Cardinality, $A'$ means Transpose of $A$.
$ My Attempt $.

det(A*A')=1
Implies, det(A)=±1,

Next, I stuck..

Comment: Can you compute the top left entry of $AA'$, for example? It will give you a very strong conditoin on three of the entries of $A$

Comment: (1 0 0) * col (1 0 0) gives first entries of AA'. -1 will also give the same result...

Answer (score 1):

Computing the top left entry of $AA'$, we find $a_{11}^2+a_{22}^2+a_{22}^2=1$. This means that exactly one of the three entries in the first row of $A$ is $\pm 1$ and the other two are $0$. The same works for the seond and third roe, i.e., each row has exactly one entry $=\pm1$ and two entries $=0$.

But we have more: If $AA'=I$, the $A'$ is the inverse of $A$ and that means that also $A'A=I$. Thus we get the row-conditions on $A$ also as row-conditions on $A'$, which means column-conditions on $A$. In other words, each column of $A$ has exactly one no-zero entry.

Therefore, we have exactly $3!$ ways to arrange the *positions* of the non-zero entries in $A$, and then we have $2^3$ ways t choose between $\pm1$ for each of them. That makes a total of 
$$3!\cdot 2^3=48$$
such matrices.